# Render Passes with Different Environment Textures in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, compositing-nodes, render-passes

Blender Wizards,

Does anyone know of a method of using render passes to export with different environment textures affecting different objects/materials? I'm using Cycles.

In my scene, I have an environment texture setup, using noise, to create an iridescent/holographic look on one of my metallic objects, but I don't want it to reflect on other metallic elements of the scene.

Render passes.. z-combine.. Light path node? Can't seem to piece this one together.